# What is the right way to use the libimobiledevice python bindings?

Tags: python, macos, libimobiledevice

I am using macOS 10.15.7.

I use pyenv to install Python 3.8.6.

I use `python -m venv myenv` to setup a virtual environment and activate that environment.

I clone the liblist repo from `https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libplist`. I then use `./autogen.sh --prefix=/Users/jamesh/tmp/local --enable-debug` to generate the Makefile. After make'ing and installing, I get the plist.so file.

```
$ pwd
/Users/jamesh/tmp/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
$ ls
plist.a   plist.la* plist.so*
```

I can cd into `/Users/jamesh/tmp/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages`, run ipython, and execute `import plist`. As it is importing, it crashes with `'ipython' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)`

I also tried a simple script with:

```
import sys
sys.path.append( "/Users/jamesh/tmp/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages" )
import plist
```

with the same result.

I figure I must be doing something wrong and cannot use the plist.so file directly.

What step am I missing?

However, I can do the basically the same on Ubuntu 18.04 and it works.